# MySQL group by TimeStamp

Tags: mysql

I am writing a Python code where I need to use MySQLdb to retrieve data from a MySQL database. A part of the original database looks like this:

[image]

I used this command

```
SELECT TimeStamp,Pac 
FROM SolarData 
WHERE DATE(`TimeStamp`) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);
```

to group the data by hour, but the result is not what i expected:

[image]

The Pac number shown for every hour is the same number as the first record of each hour. It's not an accumulated number for the whole hour. What I need is an accumulated number of the whole hour.

Comment: Please put all necessary info directly into your question. Links break and we want to preserve posts for future visitors.

Comment: You haven't asked for any agregates in your query, so you just get the values from one of the records.

Comment: We need you to put both the actual result and the desired result in this question.

Comment: editors please show the first image I linked here. I can only see the second one.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu The standard for this community is imgur. Dropbox is not accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because MySQL is like your alcoholic uncle when you don't use `GROUP BY` by the ANSI standard. You probably want:

```
SELECT HOUR(TimeStamp) AS Hour, 
    SUM(Pac) AS Pac
FROM SolarData 
WHERE `TimeStamp` >= CURDATE() 
  AND `TimeStamp` < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp);
```

It would be helpful to see the desired result you're looking for. Until then, the above query is just a guess based on *group the data by hour*. For future reference, use SQL Fiddle to post your table structure/data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got the new result. How do I decorate the code so that the hour format can have the date on it as well like this `2014-01-14 07:00`?

Answer (score 1):

> *"How do I decorate the code so that the hour format can have the date on it as well like this 2014-01-14 07:00"*

All of `Hour` belong to today (`CURDATE()`), and second part is always ':00', so following query might help you. Could try this?

```
SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', Hour, ':00'), Pac
FROM (
    SELECT HOUR(TimeStamp) AS Hour, 
        SUM(Pac) AS Pac
    FROM SolarData 
    WHERE DATE(`TimeStamp`) = CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY HOUR(TimeStamp)
) x;
```

Comment: I've got this error back `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: @Shurui Liu ooos. Sorry. I've added 'x' end of sql. This is an alias of derived table.

Comment: it brings up another error, but the error has nothing to do with MySQL. It comes from my Python code.